# animation a mask of a view

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I want to use a mask to achieve the effect that the visible part of the View changes as the mask is moved.
[image]
and this is my demo code：

```
- (void)drawLayer{
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    self.maskLayer = maskLayer;
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.underView.bounds];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(-4, -5, (self.underView.frame.size.width+8) *0.5, self.underView.frame.size.height+10);
    UIBezierPath *topPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:frame cornerRadius:frame.size.height *0.5];
    NSLog(@"maskLayerframe:%@",NSStringFromCGRect(frame));
    [path appendPath:topPath];
    maskLayer.path = path.CGPath;
    maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
    self.underView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

```
///animation
/// - Parameter swipeToRight: Whether to slide to the right
- (void)startAnimation:(BOOL)swipeToRight{
    CGFloat x = swipeToRight? self.underView.bounds.size.width *0.5-4:-4;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, -5, (self.underView.frame.size.width+8) *0.5, self.underView.frame.size.height+10);
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.underView.bounds];
    UIBezierPath *topPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:frame cornerRadius:frame.size.height *0.5];
    [path appendPath:topPath];
    maskLayer.path = path.CGPath;
    maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:NO];
    [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    self.maskLayer.frame = frame;
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

But the final animation looks like this, I don't know what's wrong with it, can anyone tell me please?

before animation
[image]

animation to right
[image]

animation back to left
[image]

Comment: Why are you using CAShapeLayer for that?

Comment: Do you want to move only light gray rect while preserving it’s size?

Comment: Do you want it to act like a UI Switch? https://images.app.goo.gl/NTtp2oamA9AmbiJg9

Answer (score -1):

I found right way to implementation it~

```
- (void)startAnimation:(BOOL)swipeToRight{
    CGFloat x = swipeToRight? self.underView.bounds.size.width *0.5-4:-4;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, -4, (self.underView.frame.size.width+8) *0.5, self.underView.frame.size.height+8);
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.underView.bounds];
    UIBezierPath *topPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:frame cornerRadius:frame.size.height *0.5];
    [path appendPath:topPath];
    maskLayer.path = path.CGPath;
    maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;
    CABasicAnimation * basicAni = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    basicAni.fromValue = (__bridge id _Nullable)(self.maskLayer.path);
    basicAni.toValue = (__bridge id _Nullable)(maskLayer.path);
    basicAni.duration = 0.4;
    basicAni.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    [self.underView.layer.mask addAnimation:basicAni forKey:@"path"];

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:true];
    self.maskLayer.path = maskLayer.path;
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

Comment: If you correct your own code, you should either **delete your question** or, if you feel it would be helpful to other developers, add some information about what you did to correct it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).